# Group by, convert to factor and extract levels as integers issue R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes with same columns (vars) and 2 different user id's:

df1:

```
structure(list(user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), obs_id = c("717b1913-0c0f-4963-8bc9-81a06a3bb1c0", 
"717b1913-0c0f-4963-8bc9-81a06a3bb1c0", "717b1913-0c0f-4963-8bc9-81a06a3bb1c0", 
"717b1913-0c0f-4963-8bc9-81a06a3bb1c0", "717b1913-0c0f-4963-8bc9-81a06a3bb1c0", 
"717b1913-0c0f-4963-8bc9-81a06a3bb1c0"), timestamp = c(337837075445301, 
337837075445301, 337837077455301, 337837077455301, 337837079457301, 
337837079457301), acc_x = c(0.5363176, 0.5363176, 0.5243462, 
0.5243462, 0.5243462, 0.5243462), acc_y = c(6.4693303, 6.4693303, 
6.4693303, 6.4693303, 6.4693303, 6.4693303), acc_z = c(6.8093176, 
6.8093176, 6.821289, 6.821289, 6.821289, 6.821289)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"obs_id", "timestamp", "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and df2:

```
structure(list(user_id = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), obs_id = c("8027eac3-8839-498e-98b9-3b46da98d1f4", 
"8027eac3-8839-498e-98b9-3b46da98d1f4", "8027eac3-8839-498e-98b9-3b46da98d1f4", 
"8027eac3-8839-498e-98b9-3b46da98d1f4", "8027eac3-8839-498e-98b9-3b46da98d1f4", 
"8027eac3-8839-498e-98b9-3b46da98d1f4"), timestamp = c(336965414272993, 
336965414272993, 336965414272993, 336965416627384, 336965418627300, 
336965420627376), acc_x = c(-1, -1, -1, 0.81644773, 0.80208206, 
0.8140534), acc_y = c(-1, -1, -1, 6.648901, 6.646507, 6.651295
), acc_z = c(-1, -1, -1, 7.2618356, 7.257047, 7.233104)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"obs_id", "timestamp", "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to bind them, group by `user_id` turn `obs_id` to factor and extract the levels out of it to be an integers column:

```
bind_rows(df1,df2) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(obs_id = as_factor(obs_id),
         replicate = as.numeric(levels(obs_id)))
```

returns an error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `replicate` must be length
>   6 (the group size) or one, not 0

Please advise what I am doing wrong here?

I want `obs_id` column to be turned to factor column, take the `levels` and "encode" it to be integer and instead the long `string` you may observe in `obs_id`.

Comment: The `as_factor` is from which package?.  You need `as.numeric(levels(obs_id))[obs_id])`

Comment: @akrun as.factor, typo. But why do I get this error?

Comment: @akrun it doesn't work here is the error:
Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector

Comment: Are you trying to get the numeric index stored in tthat one because the obs_id is clearly character

Comment: `bind_rows(df1,df2) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(obs_id = as.factor(obs_id),
         replicate = as.numeric(levels(obs_id))[obs_id])`
Doesn't work and throws the Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
error

Comment: @akrun, I am trying to transform the obs_id to number. Per user there are some unique obs_id's I need to transform them to an integer for simplicity.
That's why I have done this with factors and levels.

Comment: @akrun still throws:Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and factor vector, coercing into character vectorNAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I need it to be grouped by user_id

Comment: Each user_id has for example N unique obs_id's. I want to each of these obs_id's to be transformed to 1,2,3,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After binding the datasets, convert the 'obs_id' to `factor`, then do the `group_by` as there is a conflict when we convert to `factor` within the `group_by` as the levels can be different.  An easier option would be to `match` the 'obs_id' with `unique` elements of 'obs_id'

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  mutate(Rep = match(obs_id, unique(obs_id)))
```

---

The issue is in storing a `factor` column in each 'user_id' having different `levels`.  If the objective is to get the 'Rep' column, we don't need a `factor` intermediate column

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
     group_by(user_id) %>% 
     mutate(Rep = as.integer(factor(obs_id)))
```

Comment: But each user has it's own obs_id's so when I transform it to integers it should start over from replicate = 1

Comment: Another approach is to add these reps for each df.

Comment: @steves  Please check the update.  It should work now

Comment: You are genius! So smart and simple solution dear @akrun!!!!
Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: @steves Earlier, I got misunderstood about the objective and didn't check the column type.  The error makes sense as a column with different levels for each group is not allowed unless it is wrapped in a `list`

Comment: the solution is so simple and beautiful, I learn a lot from you!

Comment: @steves thank you for the kind words.  Have a great weekend!